# Need help with variable scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, getjson

I have the following Javascript function that should return an array of groups that are in database. It uses `$.getJSON()` method to call `get_groups.php` which actually reads from the database.

```
function get_groups() {
    var groups = [];

    $.getJSON('get_groups.php', function(response) {
        for (var i in response) {
            groups.push(response[i]);
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Unfortunately, this function does not work as expected because `groups.push(response[i]);`
 does not fill the `var groups = [];` (as I understand it fills some other `groups` array, probably the global one).

Assuming that I don't want to have a global `groups` variable, how would you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a scope issue really, it's the fact that [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is asynchronous, meaning that this part runs *after* you return:

```
for (var i in response) {
  groups.push(response[i]);
}
```

You need to call whatever function needs this data in the callback of the asynchronous request, so it runs when the data's available, like this:

```
$.getJSON('get_groups.php', function(response) {
    var groups = [];
    for (var i in response) {
        groups.push(response[i]);
    }
    doSomethingThatNeedsGroups(groups);
});
```

Currently you groups array *is* getting populated, just not when you need it to.  If you absolutely *have* to return this (I strongly recommend using the asynchronous model the way it was intended) you can use the full [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) version and set `async:false`.  Again...don't go that route if possible, stick to calling whatever function needs the data once it's available, as `async: false` will lock up the user's browser.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really have a global variable with the name `groups` (which would be not the best idea actually), you are talking to your "local" `groups` variable.

Since EMCA-/Javascript does have **function scope** and you are using a **closure** there, you do have access to that variable. So the problem here, **is not the scope.**
So even with a global variable with the exact same name, the such called lexical scope will guarantee you the access to your local variable.

The actuall problem is, that `return groups` is executed before `$.getJSON()` does complete. Since it creates an ajax request, it run asynch.

You should use a `callback` yourself to process the data:

```
function get_groups(cb) {
   var groups = [];

   $.getJSON('get_groups.php', function(response) {
       for (var i in response) {
           groups.push(response[i]);
       }
       cb.apply(null, [groups]);
   }
}

get_groups(function(groups){
   // do something with groups array
});
```

Comment: Moving the return statement doesn't work, the function will simply return nothing then.

Comment: was fixed before you send that :p

Comment: For your edit, you can do this a bit cleaner with `.call(null, groups)`, but the first part of your answer is a bit off...if there's a more local variable with the same name you're *always* using that variable, a global one will never override a more-locally scoped one.

Comment: @Nick: yay, maybe. I hoped the second part about function scope makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

"$.getJSON('get_groups.php', function(response) {" is an Callback-Function.

The changes in the groups-Array are affect after the callback is trickerd and also after you return groups.

1. get_groups enterd
2. request the url and register a callback
3. return groups
4. end of "get_groups"
5. trigger callback
6. anynomous callback-function enterd
7. modifie groups-array
8. end of anynomous callback-function

you could not return the modifies of the callback-function directly.

Comment: FYI synchronous ajax would solve the problem, but is not recommended